# Pytorch error: ImportError: cannot import name 'container_abcs' from 'torch._six'

Tags: python, pytorch, containers, importerror, torch

I'm trying to run through this tutorial for installing BindsNet and running the eth_mnist example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEl3yGqy0AU

I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "eth_mnist.py", line 12, in <module>
    from bindsnet.datasets import MNIST   File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bindsnet/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import (   File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bindsnet/datasets/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .collate import time_aware_collate   File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bindsnet/datasets/collate.py", line 11, in <module>
    from torch._six import container_abcs, string_classes, int_classes 
ImportError: cannot import name 'container_abcs' from 'torch._six' (/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_six.py)
```

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/1048

Comment: The issue “container_abcs” is solved with “import collections.abc as container_abcs”  but now the problem is with “int_classes”. ImportError: cannot import name 'int_classes' from 'torch._six'

Comment: solved by adding int_classes = int to the collate.py file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue “container_abcs” is solved with “import collections.abc as container_abcs” but now the problem is with “int_classes”. ImportError: cannot import name 'int_classes' from 'torch._six'
Edit:
solved by adding int_classes = int to the collate.py file.